# Hibernate's createSQLQuery won't retreive data

Tags: java, hibernate

Hibernate won't retrieve data even though the data exists in the table. Running the query directly from SQL Server Management Studio shows the expected results. Any idea what am I missing?

Java:

```
List<User> userCollection= session.createSQLQuery("select column1, column2 from myTable").addEntity(User.class).list();
```

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

   <session-factory>

        <property name = "hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>

        <property name = "hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://server:1433;databaseName=MyDatabase</property>

        <property name = "hibernate.connection.username">user</property>      
        <property name = "hibernate.connection.password">123</property>


        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property> -->

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->

        <mapping class="com.app.User"/>

   </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure that this code is even executed? Does your SQL server database really listen on port 8080 instead of the default port?

Comment: Just modified the question as I'm using port 1433.

Comment: So the above code was not executing at all, right? Is it now? What happens when you put a breakpoint on that line and run it with your debugger? Does it stop?

Comment: I get an empty list, if I run the exact same query directly from SQL Server I get one match. The code was modified since it contains sensitive information.

Comment: Then you're probably connecting to another server, or another database, or another schema, or with another user, or the data isn't actually in the table before you havn't committed the transaction that inserted it yet.

Comment: I'll keep looking then, will post results once I find something.